# Stack app for Android crashes when viewing posts with embedded images

Tags: bug, android-app

Every time I view a post with an embedded image using the Stack app on my [Kobo Arc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kobo_Arc) (Android e-reader/tablet using 4.1.1), the page loads as normal without the image... and then the app crashes.

I don't have an error screen to show you, because it just changes the post content to a blank white page and then quickly restarts the app.